# Can I change the version (or content) of a site based on a user ID

Tags: php, drupal, joomla, logic

If I use a backend system like drupal or joomla, would I be able to have it so that each user-type is directed to a specific version of the site with specific links available to them - rather than just "hiding" a link or article which these systems already do?

To be specific, what I'm trying to do is provide a community based studygroup site where students can contribute to each other based on the courses they register for. So ideally I don't want someone in stats to have to see a list of irrelevant channels/pages. I know that making a CRM-esque site from scratch can do this, or getting something like CRMery which is a joomla extension can also possibly do what I need by rewriting specifics within the code and design of the software (not even sure if the license would permit that). But I want to avoid the cost and more importantly time, of a CRM from scratch and was wondering if I just make different websites (or portals of some sort) available based on user login it could speed up the development cycle significantly.

I was thinking that the logic would work as follows:

visit www.communitysite.com
log in
be directed to a specific site (as there will be multiple pages relevant to the login) that contains all the details for the registered course (which would include things like embedded videos from youtube, chat system for users that are online and registered for that course, and perhaps something along the lines of note/document sharing). Someone suggested using subdomains for this - but if it grows beyond three or four courses then it becomes very impractical to have a subdomain for each subject. Also, if they select multiple courses such as bio and chem they should be able to see those as well without having to visit a new domain every time.

Any ideas or feedback would be much appreciated. I know for a fact that I can do this via a non-joomla/drupal based site, for instance using php - but being the only one in my team with a background in programming, I wanted something simple for the tutors themselves to use if they needed access to the backend.

I'm not looking for someone to do this for me, just if it's possible and maybe your ideas on a better flow of logic as I understand that this might not be the best way to manage a site like this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure of the specific drupal/joomla requirements, but essentially what would be done:

1. Upon registration of the user, assign values to the "types" of classes to which they are registered. For example, algebra, geometry, calculus would all have individual identifiers associated with them, but would also belong generally to the group "math".
2. Determine the types of groups that user would hypothetically be interested in seeing. For example, if they are enrolled in Biology 400 they would likely also be interested in something like Physics 200 or Chemistry 300.
3. When the user signs in and is redirected to their home page, your database query would be something like :

   ```
   "SELECT * FROM courses WHERE course IN (array)"
   ```

Where array would be a generic container (like math, science, language, history, psychology) holding the individual courses.

In short you would need to make sure you have a hierarchy to the courses (e.g., American History 101 -> History -> Humanities) and display only courses belonging to the same category.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, especially having a larger container to group up similar courses. I think this is probably the most practical way - and it would work well through PHP, but I'll have to see if I can some how execute custom scripts on the fly through drupal or joomla since the tutors uploading the content would not know their way around a website. Unless - there's some sort of open source CMS that would only manage pages as needed instead of the entire site.

Comment: I know for a fact that drupal allows for custom scripts, and this one would be rather easy to create. As for the tutors, you mean you need them to be able to customize the associations between groups? That also wouldn't be that hard. You could create a dropdown of all possible courses and a dropdown of all possible groups, have the tutor select a subject and add it to a specific group (or groups) and give access to that page to the tutors.

Comment: Great, thank you. I'll start looking into drupal and custom scripts!

Comment: Fahad, you can do all this without custom code. Have a look at Views, content permissions, roles in Drupal. I suggest to use Drupal 7.

Answer (score 1):

You can make course id and assign it to the userid so when some one will login based on course they have chosen you can show them specific part of site by checking course id from users table for that user.

Comment: This is a great idea!

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do something like this in Joomla (or any CMS) and how to do it really depends a lot on how complex you want to make to make the site, the work flow (are you assigning the students to classes or are they selecting) and how much custom coding you want to do. Also are these classes going to change constantly or are they set.

If people are able to select their own groups you could look a a system like jomsocial or similar.  You don't have to reinvent things, you just need to think a little differently about what tools you need.